# Select without including field in the group by

Tags: sql

I have this table:

| ID | Origin | Destination | Vessel | Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | X | 7 |
| 2 | A | D | Y | 21 |
| 3 | C | B | Y | 3 |

I performed this query:

```
Select Vessel , sum (Item) as Total
from table
group by Vessel
```

I'll have:

```
X,7 

Y ,24
```

Now comes the hard part.
The one above is a result of a view, and i have to extract data from this view.
In particular i have to extract data by Origin and Destination.
If i put both this fields in the view's select,  i have to group by by them and this results in more rows which is not what i am looking for.

My desired result would be a query where i put , for example, "A" as Origin filter and i got:

X, 7

Y , 24 (i don't mind that vessel y has a row without origin "A", it has to include all of vessel Y rows if A is included in one of them)

Other example, extracting data with Origin "C" would have this result:

Y, 24 (that's because origin C is included in vessel Y but not in vessel X)

Any idea?

---- Adding some more info regarding the view

```sql
select distinct
convert(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, MIN(PT.ETD)), MIN(ETD)))) + '/' + right('0' + convert(varchar, datepart(isoww, MIN(ETD))), 2) AS OTHERFIELDAGGREGATE,
Sum (Item1) as ITEM1, 
SUm (item2) as ITEM2,
sum (item3) as ITEM3,
PT.IDPOL as ORIGIN,
PT.IDPOD as DESTINATION,
case when condition1 = 1 then IDNave3 when condition2 = 1 then IDNave2 else IDNave1 end as VESSEL

from Table ALLO
join VESSEL1 ON = VESSEL1.ID 
join VESSEL2 ON = VESSEL2.ID 
join VESSEL3 ON = VESSEL3.ID
join ORIGIN 
join DESTINATION 
left outer join item1 --joins to other tables needed to calculate
left outer join item2--joins to other tables needed to calculate
left outer join item3--joins to other tables needed to calculate
group by

OTHERFIELDAGGREGATE
ORIGIN
DESTINATION
VESSEL
```

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead post code as plain text, formatted as "code".

Comment: Provided your DBMS supports the feature, you can use a Table valued function for that.

Comment: @Serg can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly, but if I do, you simply need to join the Vessel column onto itself, and then filter on the Origin column as below:

```
SELECT TT2.Vessel, SUM(TT2.Item) As Items
FROM TestTable TT
JOIN TestTable TT2 ON TT.Vessel = TT2.Vessel
WHERE TT.Origin = 'A'
GROUP BY TT2.Vessel
```

That way if you filter by A you'd get X:7, Y:24 and if you filter by  C you'd get Y:24

If you want to split these into a "view" and "stored procedure" you can do so as follows:

Update your View to be:

```
SELECT TT.Origin, TT.Destination, TT.Vessel, TT2.Item
FROM TestTable TT
JOIN TestTable TT2 ON TT.Vessel = TT2.Vessel
```

And then your stored procedure can be :

```
 SELECT Vessel, SUM(Item) As Items
 FROM View
 GROUP BY Vessel
```

Comment: Uhm , A would be fine, but B should have been X:7, Y:24

Also, i misproperly called it "Table" but on a larger perspective i have a view that picks from that table.
Then i have a stored procedure that filters the view, so in the view i have to select Origin and destination somehow

Comment: @AndreaG I updated my code, I meant to say C would be Y:24, There is no Origin B. If you do not include the data in the table, you can't filter on it. So as I suggested, update your View to join the Vessel column onto itself. Then use your stored procedure to filter  on the Origin/Destination column

Comment: How can i filter a view with a stored procedure if the fields that i have to filter are not in the view itself? 
I mean, i can join the vessel onto itself like you did in the code, but if i filter by origin in the stored procedure, i'll get an invalid column name error.

Maybe i am missing something :)

Comment: @AndreaG I have updated my answer, does that help you?

Comment: Oh you moved the Sum in the stored, i'll try that!

Comment: No my SUM has to be inside the view , there are other fields that has some aggregates like Min or Max

Comment: @AndreaG perhaps if you include the additional columns in your example it would help me understand your problem.

Comment: Tried to put some more info

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
Select Vessel, sum(Item) as Total
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.vessel = t.vessel and
                    t2.origin = 'C'
             )
group by Vessel;
```

Or do this using a `having` clause:

```
Select Vessel, sum(Item) as Total
from table t
group by Vessel
having sum(case when t.original = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: My table is actually a view, and the filter on origin or destination has to be inside a stored procedure , so i have somehow to put both origin and destination in the view's select

Comment: @AndreaG . . . That doesn't make sense at all.  Views don't take parameters.

Comment: Yes i know, but i have a stored procedure that reads from that view.
Origin and destination are parameters passed to that stored procedure.